# Nginx location block equivalent in Apache (for passing to different php-fpm versions)

Tags: nginx, php, apache-2.4, php-fpm

I need to have PHP 5 and 7 working concurrently because of the need to use two PHP extensions that are only built for exclusively versions 5 and 7.

I've got this working with Nginx by naming the pages that call on the PHP 5 extension to e.g. page.php5, and having location blocks as follows:

```
location ~ \.php5$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}
```

Works fine. But how to do the same with Apache? I've read about having different virtual hosts, one using a PHP module and one using fast-cgi, but ideally I'd rather have something much closer to the location method above and have just the one host.

Can this be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the manual for [mod_proxy_fcgi](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_fcgi.html) for the correct syntax to pass needed options but the equivalent would roughly be to use a [`ProxyPassMatch`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassmatch):

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php5(/.*)?)$ unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$  unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
```

Comment: Ok thanks. It doesn't seem there's a sanctioned Apache release for my distro that supports unix sockets for ProxyPassMatch yet, but I'll return to it at a later date (getting this working on Apache isn't urgent).